# Adding dependency on another standalone Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee

I am creating two different but related applications. The first application is the backend for an iPhone/Android application, while the other one is a virtual store. These two systems are not dependent on each other. So I could deploy only the virtual store or only the backend.

Both of these application should authenticate against the same user database. So I have started on a third application for accessing this database which holds the user objects.
The first thing that I thought was that this application could also stand on it own.

The question is how I should use this shared user repository application in the other applications?

- Should I create a dependency on the service-layer artifact and the domain-artifact and import the Spring config file in the other applications that I create?
- Should I create a web service so I can make requests for user data in the other applications?

Or are there other options that are better? Both the backend and virtual store are web service with REST principles applied. In the virtual store for instance I need to have access to user data from the common repository as well as adding store specific details.

Comment: I assume the common web application is a maven WAR project?

Comment: @JamesB Not yet. It is currently only a JAR. I have domain, repository and service layer. That is the user application. The one that both the other application depends on since they will authenticate the user and so on against it.

Comment: Which layers are to be used by other applications?

Comment: The service layer for getting information from the underlying database that keeps all user information + the domain layer for having access to the classes like `User` etc. This would mean two Maven dependencies then.

Comment: I would understand another project depending on the domain, not sure about service layer though. Why do the other apps depend on the service layer?

Comment: How about using a something like JMS - It allows the communication between different components of a distributed application to be loosely coupled, reliable, and asynchronous.

Comment: @MystyxMac Yeah, JMS may be a better solution eventually. But would bundling the JAR for the user repository in each application be bad solution?

Comment: @LuckyLuke I don't think bundling the user repository jar is a bad idea. As long as the datasource is configurable.

Comment: The datasource is configured on the JBoss server so that is ok. I think I will give it a try. I can't see that it is wrong either. I guess what I eventually do is to look at LDAP/Active directory. Doesn't it sound like I have to go in that direction eventually? But right now I guess this will be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I do like this (Project A is used in B.) :-

To use one project into another project I m using **httpcomponents-client-4.2.2** library.

**Step 1 :** Copied jar of A in B.

**Step 2 : In Project B :-**

```
HTTPClientHelper httpClientHelper = new HTTPClientHelper();
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClientHelper.GET(uri + param);
InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
//    ... do other stuffs
```

**Step 3 :** In HTTPClientHelper class

```
// Constructor
public HTTPClientHelper() {
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
}

// Execute HTTP GET method of given Service URL
public HttpEntity GET(String url) {
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(get, localContext);
        httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return httpEntity;
}

// Execute HTTP POST method of given Service URL
public HttpEntity POST(String url, boolean sendData) {

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    if (sendData) {
        post.setEntity(getUrlEncodedFormEntity());
    }
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(post, localContext);
        httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return httpEntity;
}

// Create a list of <name, value> for user name & password
public void createHttpEntity(String name, String value) {
    try {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        setUrlEncodedFormEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public UrlEncodedFormEntity getUrlEncodedFormEntity() {
    return urlEncodedFormEntity;
}

public void setUrlEncodedFormEntity(UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity) {
    this.urlEncodedFormEntity = urlEncodedFormEntity;
}
```

Comment: How on earth does this answer the question?